# What Google Account is associated with an OAuth Client ID?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We have some old configurations which make use of an OAuth Client ID, and we're trying to determine which Google Developer account created it.

We have both the client ID and secret.  Is is possible for us to determine which Google account they're associated with?  We'd prefer to not have to switch to a new account.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this client ID still used on some website for sign-in? If so, you could try to sign-in with an account that hasn't authenticated yet, and in the auth window click on the App name to get the developer info including the email address, which should match the Google account you are looking for.

[image]