# How do I identify the Google account that generated an OAuth Client ID

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

Our problem is, in essence, the same as the one presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813743/what-google-account-is-associated-with-an-oauth-client-id). We have multiple in-house client libraries with Client IDs and Secrets hard-coded in them. API access is currently working, but if we should need to make any changes with regard to these credentials, we would be unable to because we cannot determine the Google account associated with them.

I have logged into https://console.developers.google.com/ for the accounts that I expected these credentials to be associated with, but there are no existing projects listed for these accounts. And since these credentials are used strictly for server-to-server communication (ex: retrieving google analytics data from the API), the solution proposed there for discovering the account does not apply.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

TIA